# change localhost to another domain

Tags: solr

I have downloaded lucene solr 
and I start it by typing in the `bin` directory
`./solr start` and so on.

For now the url to access solr is in the localhost domain: `http://localhost:8983/solr/`

I'd like to change it to another domain, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: how do you want it.../

Comment: What do you mean? 
You know, normally with the Apache http server I can define the domain name. Here with the solr server I don't know how to do it.

Edit:
I still want to run solr on localhost, but I want it to be accessible on e.g. mydomain.com. Is it to be done only over solr or should I change something in the operation system configuration (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make an alias for your localhost? 
Then you have to edit your hosts and virtualhost config file. Please be more specific!

Comment: Sorry if I'm not specific. Thank you for your answer. After I do what you wrote, do I have to specify the alias somewhere in the solr configuration files or while starting solr or do I have to take care of something else?

Comment: What I'm wondering is: I stopped apache2 by `sudo service apache2 stop`, localhost is not accesssible, but localhost:8983 where solr is is accessible. Is it possilbe that solr runs on its own server?

Comment: localhost means localhost:80. Solr runs on an other port with his own webserver. What do you want exactly?

Comment: Exactly, I want to try the solr Replication with master and slave. However I have only one machine.